# Is it possible to add pager inside navigation tabs in android

Tags: android, navigation, android-viewpager

I want to add pager(navigated using swipe left and right) inside a navigation tabs(also swipes left and right).

I am asking about the touch events(swiping)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ChildFragmentManager for managing fragments inside one page of the Pager.